# iOS Facebook integration,FBConditionalLog

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

I know this question has been asked many times, I've already done my research both on stackoverflow and on google, but nothing came up that resolves my problem.

I'm trying to integrate Facebook login in my application. I'm using the latest Facebook SDK which can be downloaded [here](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/). I'm not only trying to integrate Facebook login, but also other Social network login as well. So far, I'm able to accomplish them.

To integrate Facebook login, I've followed this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/). I've done exactly the same. My problem is that when user clicked on **Facebook login button**. Facebook login page appears in the browser, then asks for permissions. So far, it's working. After completing user credentials then  click **login button** on the browser, I got this log **FBConditionalLog: handleOpenURL should not be called once a session has closed**, I got no error. Also, in my Facebook account, I've seen that I've permitted the application in the app settings. Normally, I would have got **user session found** log, if user was able to login successfully.

Do you have any idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the login tutorial sample: https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.1-howtos/tree/master/LoginHowTo - work for you? It almost seems like the session has been closed by the time the login request has been sent out.

Comment: @CAbernathy,i didn't try that. But,i gave up using official Facebook SDK. Instead, i'm using [this](https://github.com/hiddenmemory/facebook-ios-sdk) , i found that it's much better than official one.